# Sql query to convert nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to query for total amount of a column using an aggregate function. The column data type is NVARCHAR(MAX).  How can I convert it to Integer?

I have tried this:

```
  SELECT SUM(CAST(amount AS INT)),
         branch 
    FROM tblproducts  
   WHERE id = 4
GROUP BY branch
```

...but I'm getting:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3600.00' to data type int.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

3600.00 is not integer so CAST via float first

```
sum(CAST(CAST(amount AS float) AS INT))
```

Edit:

Why float?

- no idea of precision or scale across all rows: float is the lesser evil perhaps
- empty string will cast to zero for float, fails on decimal
- float accepts stuff like 5E-02, fails on decimal

Comment: why did you choose float, as opposed to decimal?  I'm just curious/trying to learn :)

Comment: @JNK: because it's more tolerant then decimal. We have no idea of precision or scale, empty string will cast to zero for float, float accepts stuff like 5E-02...

Answer (score 8):

In addition to gbn's answer, you need to protect against non-numeric cases:

```
sum(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Amount)=1 THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS float) AS INT)END )
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sum(Try_Parse(amount as Int Using 'en-US')),
         branch 
    FROM tblproducts
   WHERE id = 4
GROUP BY branch