# How to convert Nvarchar column to INT

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, integer, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

I have a `nvarchar` column in one of my tables. Now I need to convert that column values to `INT` type..

I have tried using

```
cast(A.my_NvarcharColumn as INT)
```

and

```
convert (int, N'A.my_NvarcharColumn')
```

When I ran my query I am getting errors like

> *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' 23454542 ' to
>   data type int.*

hi i am posting my entire code snippet

```
SELECT A.objID, name, des,  right(Replace(Ltrim(Replace(substring(my_nvarcharcolumn,1,9), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'),10) AS new_nvarcharcolumn 
INTO #tmp1
FROM [database].[dbo].[tblname] AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].tblname1 WHERE sourceID = 32) AS AI ON source = A.objID
INNER JOIN [database].[dbo].tblname2 AS I ON I.ObjectID = A.Source

SELECT MAX(m_dAddDate) AS date_Asof, dnum INTO #tmp2 FROM 
(SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].tblname WHERE senior <> '' AND class = 'SSS') AS A
GROUP BY dnum

SELECT DISTINCT A.* INTO #tmp3 FROM #tmp1 AS A
INNER JOIN #tmp2 AS SD ON SD.dnum =cast(A.new_nvarcharcolumn as INT)
INNER JOIN database.[dbo].tbl4 AS M ON M.dnum = cast(A.new_nvarcharcolumn as INT)  AND SD.date_Asof = M.adddate
```

Comment: Cast works perfectly fine for me, could you post the complete code snippet, may be the error is because of something else

Comment: hi marc_s, nope its not working, it's saying Error converting datatype nvarchar to bigint

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql query to convert nvarchar to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790591/sql-query-to-convert-nvarchar-to-int)

Comment: Make sure there are no commas in your numbers. ISNUMERIC('1.500.00') = 1, but CAST('1,500.00' as float) = ERROR cannot convert NVARCHAR value to FLOAT.

Answer (score 35):

`CONVERT` takes the column name, not a string containing the column name; your current expression tries to convert the string `A.my_NvarcharColumn` to an integer instead of the column content.

```
SELECT convert (int, N'A.my_NvarcharColumn') FROM A;
```

should instead be

```
SELECT convert (int, A.my_NvarcharColumn) FROM A;
```

Simple SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24d46/2).

Comment: hi, i tried changing the convert function still facing same problem

Comment: @user1348424 Then I suspect you have some invisible character in your nvarchar column. Could you try `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, A.my_NvarcharColumn) FROM A;` and post the result for one of your values that won't convert?

Comment: @user1348424 Odd, `CONVERT` to `VARBINARY` shouldn't make less records show up, that should only be limited by the `WHERE` clause. No errors or warning messages?

Answer (score 14):

You can always use the `ISNUMERIC` helper function to convert only what's really numeric:

```
SELECT
     CAST(A.my_NvarcharColumn AS BIGINT)
FROM 
     A
WHERE
     ISNUMERIC(A.my_NvarcharColumn) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its Too late But I hope it will work new comers
Try This Its Working ... :D

```
select 
  case 
      when isnumeric(my_NvarcharColumn) = 1 then 
              cast(my_NvarcharColumn AS int)
      else
              NULL
 end

AS 'my_NvarcharColumnmitter'
from A
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CAST() looks correct.

Your CONVERT() is not correct.  You are quoting the column as a string.  You will want something like

```
CONVERT(INT, A.my_NvarcharColumn)
```

** notice without the quotes **

The only other reason why this could fail is if you have a non-numeric character in the field value or if it's out of range.

You can try something like the following to verify it's numeric and return a NULL if it's not:

```
SELECT
 CASE
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(A.my_NvarcharColumn) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, A.my_NvarcharColumn)
  ELSE NULL
 END AS my_NvarcharColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert from char to int, why not think about **unicode** number?

```
SELECT UNICODE(';') -- 59
```

This way you can convert any char to int without any error. Cheers.