# SQL Select range for nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select from tables where the `column_a` in range 55 -  42000.

Note : `column_a`'s datatype is in `nvarchar`

I have try like this, but no luck

```
SELECT 
   SoftwareName, SoftwareImageTeaser, SoftwarePrice, SoftwareDescription
FROM 
   View_Software_Listing_With_Category 
WHERE 
   (SoftwarePrice >= '55' AND SoftwarePrice <= '42000')
```

Comment: if you need to treat the column as an int, why are you storing it as a varchar?

Comment: I'm assuming `column_a` here refers to `SoftwarePrice`?

Comment: @asprin yup, column_a is SoftwarePrice,

Comment: @MarcB because i dont have control on the data entry part. This is the existing data which already inserted before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,As your `SoftwarePrice` column is nvarchar, you need to convert it in Integer for comparing with integer values. Then you can use `between` clause for filtering records.

```
SELECT SoftwareName,SoftwareImageTeaser,SoftwarePrice,SoftwareDescription
FROM View_Software_Listing_With_Category 
WHERE Cast(SoftwarePrice as Int) between 55 AND 42000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SoftwareName,SoftwareImageTeaser,SoftwarePrice,SoftwareDescription
FROM View_Software_Listing_With_Category 
WHERE (CAST(CAST(SoftwarePrice AS FLOAT) AS INT) BETWEEN 55 AND 42000
```

Comment: Why do you cast it as float first and then recast it as int?

Comment: [Because sometimes it is better to play safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3790617/3444240)